# how to limit string to have specific letters in C++

Tags: c++, string

So basically I made a program that takes some input from the user and stores it in the variable. But the problem is that i want user to input Nucleotide DNA sequence and since the DNA sequence only consists of the Letters ATGC, i want to limit the input and only include these characters and if the user inputs some other character it shows an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string DNAsequence;
    cout<<"Enter the DNA sequence : ";
    cin>> DNAsequence;
    cout<< "Your 5 to 3 DNA sequence is "<<DNAsequence;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Build your own class that has `std::string` as the member, and build your own `>>` operator for `std::istream`. Consider a `std::vector` of an `enum` instead? You could have some fun here and use two bytes to store each nucleotide.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  What is your question?  You got as far as "I want to do xxx." but then you need to follow up with "so I tried yyy, and I expected zzz, but what actually happened was xyz"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment by Bathsheba, this sounds like something to be handled in a custom `>>` overload.

First lets define a type that holds a string and is parametrized on the allowed letters:

```
template <char ...allowed_chars>
struct DNASequence {
    std::string value;
};
```

The output operator is simple:

```
template <char ...allowed_chars>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const DNASequence<allowed_chars...>& dna){
    out << dna.value;
    return out;
}
```

A function that checks if a given letter is allowed:

```
template <char ...allowed_chars>
bool check(char c){
    auto eq = [](char a,char b){ return a==b;};
    return (eq(c,allowed_chars) || ...);
}
```

Now the input operator can just read a string like usually and then check each character of that string:

```
template <char ...allowed_chars>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, DNASequence<allowed_chars...>& dna){
    std::string temp;
    in >> temp;
    for (const auto& c : temp) {
        if (! check<allowed_chars...>(c)){
            in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return in;
        }
    }
    dna.value = temp;
    return in;
}
```

Main can look like this:

```
int main ()
{
    DNASequence<'A','C','G','T'> dna;
    std::cout << "Enter the DNA sequence : ";
    if (std::cin >> dna) {
        std::cout << "Your 5 to 3 DNA sequence is " << dna;
    } else {
        std::cout << "invalid input";
    }
}
```

I suppose you want to reset `std::cin`s error state and use a loop to ask the user again in case they entered invalid input.

Complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/r4947G5sP

Comment: Nice, have an upvote. Would be even nicer if somehow you could arrange things so `DNASequence<'A','C','G','T'>` and `DNASequence<'C','A','G','T'>` are the same type!

Comment: @Bathsheba my first idea was rather to rearrange it such that what currently is my `DNASeuence` is just a wrapper for a `std::string&` merely acting as an "input manipulator" to get a valid `string`. Anyhow, there is lots of room for improvement, eg use enum instead

Answer (score -1):

you can use cin.get() function in cycle and check input characters

```
string GetStringFromConsole(){
    string Returner;
    char ch=0;

    while (ch = cin.get()){
        switch (ch){
        case 'A':
        case 'T':
        case 'G':
        case 'C':
            Returner += ch;
            break;
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Wrong input: " << ch << endl;
            cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
            Returner = "";
            break;
        }

        if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
            break;
    }

    cout << Returner.data() << endl;
    return Returner;
}
```

Comment: `Returner.size() - 1` is evil if `Returner` is empty.

Comment: Returner  can't  be empty

Comment: Consider calculating (`Returnerner.size() - 1`) once and placing into a temporary variable.  You are using it 7 times and it only needs to be calculated once.  Same with `Returner[]` also, consider placing into a single char variable.

Comment: Returnerner.size() is different in each step

Comment: @tho Compilers don't need that sort of help. `Returner.size() - 1` is [evaluated](https://godbolt.org/z/M7ceWKqW3) no more often than necessary.